# Which mathematical writers have a style similar to Vladimir Arnold's?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Apologies if this question is too broad or vague for the site. But I am interested to know if there are any other writers with a style similar to that of [V.I. Arnold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Arnold#Popular_mathematical_writings), that is to say:

- Concise, getting straight to the point without much wordiness
- Emphasising geometrical understanding of concepts where possible
- Readable, rather than the dry "Theorem-Lemma-Proof" style of many math books
- Relatively easy to read for physicists
- Emphasising intuition and conceptual understanding

Comment: I'd recommend Nick Trefethen (topics include Approximation theory, Numerical analysis, Non-normal matrices and operators, theory of pseudospectra etc). Perhaps he doesn't focus too much on geometrical understanding, but he likes to see things from both a mathematical and a physical perspective that usually is enough to give you a mental picture of what's going on.

Comment: I recommend Jean Dieudonne's *Infinitesimal calculus*. Despite Arnold's disparaging of contemporary French mathematics, Jean wrote just like Arnold would like, full of geometry and examples.